# Aggregate query on time in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB Aggregate pipeline and for most of the things I want to do, it's perfect so far.

However, I'd like to aggregate on time and group by individual days, hours or minutes. This is my query so far (in the case of minute granularity:

```
db.track.aggregate(
  [
    {$match: {event: /pricing/i}},
    {$unwind:"$userId"},
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {min: {$minute: "$timestamp"}},
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

The obvious problem here is that it will group minutes of different hours together. like so:

```
{ "_id" : { "min" : 18 }, "count" : 8 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 33 }, "count" : 18 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 10 }, "count" : 6 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 8 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 43 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 35 }, "count" : 6 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 46 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 12 }, "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 31 }, "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : { "min" : 4 }, "count" : 14 }
```

I want to use the result of that query in a graph.  Ideally, I would like to get back something like that:

```
{ "_id" : { "time" : "14:04" }, "count" : 14 }
```

My document look like this

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("54cd7b8f7e4515a41898faac"),
    userId: [
        "xp1ungmsrh3hbhjk7c2go45xxvh0uiaa9rel5",
        "a3c10b3c-3825-4b32-9a57-0e75b508d5bb"
    ],
    type: "track",
    timestamp: ISODate("2015-02-01T01:04:13.632Z"),
    event: "View Pricing Page"
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here but [the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#date-expressions) doesn't give me anything else to go on.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: some sample documents  would be nice

Comment: @Disposer added a sample doc . Sorry I forgot about that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uae this query:

```
db.track.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: {event: /pricing/i} },
    { $unwind: "$userId" },
    {
      $group: 
      {
        _id: 
        {
            hour : { $hour : "$timestamp" },
            min: { $minute : "$timestamp" }
        },
        count: {$sum : 1}
      }
    },
    { $project : { _id : 0, count: 1, time : { $concat :[ {$substr:['$_id.hour', 0, 4]}, ':', {$substr:['$_id.min', 0, 4]}] }} },
  ]
)
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "count" : 2,
            "time" : "1:4"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you change the last `$project` to below, the output will be exactly as you mentioned

```
{ $project : { _id : 0, count: 1, '_id.time' : { $concat :[ {$substr:['$_id.hour', 0, 4]}, ':', {$substr:['$_id.min', 0, 4]}] }} },
```

Output:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "time" : "1:4"
            },
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of a combined _id in your `$group` and a `$project` to create the time.

```
db.track.aggregate(
  [
    {$match: {event: /pricing/i}},
    {$unwind:"$userId"},
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {min: {$minute: "$timestamp"}, hour: {$hour: "$timestamp"}},
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }
    },
    {$project: {time: {$concat:["$hour",":","$min"]}}}
  ]
)
```